# jQuery toggle function stop disappear subitems

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I have got code like this:

```
<div class="row menu-container">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-10">
        <h4 class="menu-title">Item<span class="menu-bold">1</span></h4>
        <ul id="menu-1" class="menu">
            <li id="menu-item-222"><span>Subitem1</span></li>
            <li id="menu-item-223"><span>Subitem2</span></li>
            <li id="menu-item-224"><span>Subitem3</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-10">
        <h4 class="menu-title">Item<span class="menu-bold">2</span></h4>
        <ul id="menu-2" class="menu">
            <li id="menu-item-237"><span>Subitem1</span></li>
            <li id="menu-item-239"><span>Subitem2</span></li>
            <li id="menu-item-241"><span>Subitem3</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$("h4.menu-title").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).siblings("ul").toggle();
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).siblings("ul").toggle();
});
```

I want to mouseenter `Item 1` and then show up subitems, but when I want to go through subitems they disappear. Is it possible to do keep it displayed while I am on them?

Full example on: https://jsfiddle.net/pfjsxj58/

Comment: May be you need https://jsfiddle.net/80z4mb15/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because the `mouseout` is called when you leave the `h4` to select an option in the `ul`. Instead, attach the events to the parent `div` element which is holding both the `h4` and the `ul`:

```html
<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-10 item-group">
    <h4 class="menu-title">Item<span class="menu-bold">1</span></h4>
    <ul id="menu-1" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-222"><span>Subitem1</span></li>
        <li id="menu-item-223"><span>Subitem2</span></li>
        <li id="menu-item-224"><span>Subitem3</span></li>
    </ul>
</div> 
<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-10 item-group">
    <h4 class="menu-title">Item<span class="menu-bold">2</span></h4>
    <ul id="menu-2" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-237"><span>Subitem1</span></li>
        <li id="menu-item-239"><span>Subitem2</span></li>
        <li id="menu-item-241"><span>Subitem3</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```js
$(".item-group").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).find("ul").toggle();
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).find("ul").toggle();
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/pfjsxj58/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, you have to modify your HTML and make your subitems childs of the item witch show your options. 
In that way, your element keep the focus, and you can click on subitems